# How to extract a numeric substring from a string but only if the previous string part matches a target

Tags: regex

So I am trying to extract defect numbers from changeset comments in TFS.  However, there are several ways people have entered the numbers:

1. `"Defect 1321: blah blah blah"`
2. `"Fixes HPQC 1427. Logic modified"`
3. `"- Bug 976 - Customer"`

I am not great with regexes so any help would be great.  I prepare the string ahead of time by tolowering it and stripping out the `#` and `.`, so I can be assured I am looking for something that starts with `(defect|hpqc|bug)` has an optional space (`\s`) then a number (`\d`) then ends with a space (`\s`) but this didn't work:

```
(defect|hpqc|bug)\s\d\s
```

I only want to find the first match.
I want to extract the numeric component but only if the previous word is a match.

I am sure this is a result of my trivial knowledge of regex creation.

Comment: The reason I can't use just \d is a few changesets have the date included or some other irrelevant number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this regex should work for you:

```
(?:defect|hpqc|bug)\s+(\d+)\s+
```

Defect/Bug # is available in matched group #1

Answer (score 2):

Case matters (usually) and you want more than one digit `\d+` and there is an optional number sign too so something like this should work, depending on your system:

```
(Defect|HPQC|Bug)\s*#?\s*(\d+)
```

This allows spaces and `#` or neither before the digits, and captures the digits. It would help to know if you are using python or something else (tag your question).

Comment: This works but I went with the other answer.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for the number after the keyword here is a regex might should help...

```
(?<=(Defect|HPQC|Bug)\s*#?\s*)\d+
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I precise Beroe response :

```
(?:Defect|HPQC|Bug)\s*\#?\s*(\d+)`
```

`(?:Defect|HPQC|Bug)` : detect but don't capture

`\#` : slash for disable the comment

It works for me on Expresso